# ¿Porque sucede esto en c# con una petición POST?

Tags: c#, api, web, http

espero que se encuentren bien. Escribo esta pregunta porque no entiendo que está sucediendo en este flujo y porque una tarea me esta respondiendo de esta manera.

Resulta que estoy trabajando con un servicio web que entrega información tributaria,de las empresas que uno suscribe a su servicio, Datamart. Yo por medio de una solicitud POST a mi controlador web capturo la información de la empresa para suscribirla mediante otra solicitud al servicio externo.

Mi controlador luce de esta manera

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[Authorization]
[EnableCors("corsLocalHost")]
public async Task<SubscriptionDatamartResponse> SaveAccountSII([FromBody] AccountSIIRequest request)
        {
            Datamart datamart = new Datamart(true);
            var response = await datamart.subscribeCompanyTributary(request);
            

            if (response == null) return new SubscriptionDatamartResponse()
            {
                Codigo = "99",
                Mensaje = "Ocurrio un error interno",
                SolicitudId = ""
            };
            return response;
        }
```

El método que ejecuta la suscripción esta alojado en otra clase y luce de la siguiente manera

```
public async Task<SubscriptionDatamartResponse> subscribeCompanyTributary(AccountSIIRequest account)
        {
            string rutFormat = account.RutProveedor.Replace(".", "");
            string url = "https://homo.datamart.cl/cte/v1/subscriptions/clientId/" + rutFormat + "/async";
            SubscriptionDatamartRequest request = new SubscriptionDatamartRequest()
            {
                CredencialesAutenticacion = new CredentialsAuthorization()
                {
                    Tipo = "ClaveTributaria",
                    Usuario = account.Usuario,
                    Password = account.Password,
                },
                ExtrasNotificacion = null
            };
            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);
            var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", ApiFactoringConfiguration.ApiDatamartQA.ApiKey);
            var httpResponse = await client.PostAsync(url, data);
            if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                SubscriptionDatamartResponse response = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SubscriptionDatamartResponse>(result);
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                var result = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Hasta el llamado todo bien, la empresa queda suscrita a la información tributaria pero no puedo devolver la respuesta completa que entrega el servicio. Sino que me retorna lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No estoy muy familiarizado con las Task y Async, sé que es para seguir ejecutando instrucciones mientras la respuesta se resuelve, no sé si sera ese el error. Cuando intento deserializar la respuesta para devolverla a mi controlador y alli manejar los resultados, se salta ese paso y responde automáticamente esa respuesta. A pesar de que el flujo se realiza correctamente, quiero capturar esa respuesta para devolver una clase que contiene ciertos parametros como codigo, solicitudId, mensaje y asi consultar por el estado de esa suscripción o para otros fines.

La verdad, no he podido identificar porque no me deserealiza la respuesta sino que retorna inmediatamente.

Comment: TE esta devolviendo un 405... no estas logueado... tu metodo tiene [Authorize]
[Authorization].. capaz por eso no hace nada?

Comment: No, me esta devolviendo 405 por que no tiene body en la respuesta. Ya encontré el error y es debido a que tengo que devolver un HttpResponseMessage.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tenía era que estaba devolviendo un objeto HttpResponseMessage y yo lo estaba tomando como una clase de SubscriptionResponse.

Answer (score 0):

Si ya resolviste el problema en hora buena.
Pero tengo sugerencias para el manejo de métodos de respuesta en tu servicio.

```
public IActionResult SaveAccountSII([FromBody] AccountSIIRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        Datamart datamart = new Datamart(true);
        var response = await datamart.subscribeCompanyTributary(request);

        if (response == null) return new SubscriptionDatamartResponse()
        {
            Codigo = "99",
            Mensaje = "Ocurrio un error interno",
            SolicitudId = ""
        };

        return Ok(response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }       
}
```

1. Primero. Usa IActionResult para el retorno de información, es muy útil con los códigos de error posible. Podrás encontrar mas información aquí: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-6.0
2. Trata de hacer uso de Try Catch, para manejar posibles errores y así poder dar mas rápido con los problemas.